# GSAP is not working properly after refreshing the page (in react.js)

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks, gsap

I am trying out some gsap animation on my page and initially, it works properly, but when I refresh the same page, it gets stuck at a different position which is mentioned in the .from() method.

how to fix this? and how to implement a scrolTtrigger in it?

**code:**

```
  useEffect(()=>{

    gsap.from(head_txt_ref.current, {
      duration:0.8,
      y: "50px",
    })

  },[])
```

**[full code](https://codesandbox.io/s/gsap-testing-87of9l?file=/src/App.js)**

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue. this is because the `gsap.from()` method is changing the value of its initial state, after loading. when we try to reload the page the animation is working. It is because of the change in initial state. `useLayoutEffect()` provides us with a cleanup function that we can use to kill animations. Proper animation cleanup is crucial to avoid unexpected behaviour with React 18's strict mode. `gsap.context()` makes cleanup nice and simple, all GSAP animations and ScrollTriggers created within the function get collected up so that you can easily `revert()` ALL of them at once.

We can also use this cleanup function to kill anything else that could cause a memory leak, like an event listener.

this is the example of the code which the issue has been solved.

```
import React, { useLayoutEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import gsap from 'gsap';

const Hero = () => {
  const boxRef = useRef(null);


  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const box1 = boxRef.current;

    let ctx = gsap.context(() => {
      gsap.from(box1, {
        rotation: 180,
        x: 100,
        duration: 2,
        delay: 1,
        lazy: false
      });
    });

    return () => ctx.revert();

  }, []);

  return (
    <div ref={boxRef} className='box1'></div>
  );
};

export default Hero;
```